# Fastapi OAuth2PasswordRequestForm - add a custom field 'rentalpoint' into validation form

Tags: python, fastapi

Is it possible to add a custom field into the OAuth2PasswordRequestForm? I need the content of the field to be returned in the token as "rentalpoint". Now in the return "rentalpoint" holds a fixed string `"rentalpoint": "cologne"` but i want to replace it with something like this: `"rentalpoint": request.rentalpoint`. How can i do that?

```
@router.post('/')
def login(request: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == request.username).first()
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail='Invalid credentials')
    if not Hash.verify(user.password, request.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail='Incorrect password')
    access_token = JWTtoken.create_access_token(data={"sub": user.email})
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer", "rentalpoint": "cologne", "user_id": request.username}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd work, but usually you'd add a `Form` element to your view signature: `def login(request: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(database.get_db), rental_point = Form(...)):`

Comment: Hi, do you have any example how to use such a Form element?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - what I included is an example of how to do it; you add it to the view signature and see if it gets populated with the submitted value. However, I'm not sure if it gives you much to just return the rentalpoint back to the user - you could just store it in the client, since the user is the one submitting it anyway?